# javascript can't change input value through console

Tags: javascript, input, setattribute

hi so I can't change the value of classname, as it only changes the view not truly change
I tried using

```js
var search = document.getElementsByClassName("r-30o5oe");
var s = search[0];
s.value = "0.1";
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7IIWv.jpg
I've tried using setattribute but it never worked with getelementsbyclassname for me, only works with id (which that element doesn't have), and if I tried using

```js
var search = document.getElementsByClassName("r-30o5oe")[0];
search.setAttribute("value", "2")
```

but it says undefined
I just wanna change the value of twitter's search by console by classname
its weird if I tried doing that to this page it works tho

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("s-input__search")[0].value = "0.1"
```

any solutions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically change form input from Firefox/Chrome console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37351042/dynamically-change-form-input-from-firefox-chrome-console)

Comment: The first example should work fine as long as the element with that classname exists. Please may you make sure the code is being run _after_ the HTML exists?

Comment: Why are you assuming that your first example doesn't change value of this input?

Comment: you guys can try it by yourselves go to twitter n type it, if you click on the search button again value immediately disappears, so its only a view, also if you edit the value by inspect element it will reset too